# How stable is a CordaRPCConnection?

Tags: corda

Does Corda manage `CordaRPCConnection` in the sense that a connection would be re-established after a temporary network failure, etc.?

Are clients that rely on a *long running* RPC-connection advised to monitor the state of the connection themselves and create new connections manually?

Answer (score 0):

They currently need to be somewhat managed by the client. Information on this subject can be found here - https://docs.corda.r3.com/releases/4.0/clientrpc.html?highlight=rpc#connection-management.

The client should be able to reconnect but this area is not perfected.

Work is also being done to improve this. More specifically, around retriggering observables that the client has opened. This will allow the client to open an observable and forget about it with the connection management being handled by the internal corda rpc code.

Some of the WIP code can be found in - https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/client/rpc/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/client/rpc/internal/ReconnectingCordaRPCOps.kt

and some information about it here - https://docs.corda.net/clientrpc.html#reconnecting-rpc-clients